# Using xPath find all elements where text contains 'en':

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<svg width="400" height="550">
  <g style="enable-background:new"> 
    <rect x="40" y="20" width="300" height="450" style="fill:url(#MyGradient)" />     <g style="font-size:75px;fill:#888888;fill-opacity:.6"> 
      <text x="50" y="90" filter="url(#normal)">Normal</text> 
      <text x="50" y="180" filter="url(#multiply)">Multiply</text> 
      <text x="50" y="270" filter="url(#screen)">Screen</text> 
      <text x="50" y="360" filter="url(#darken)">Darken</text> 
      <text x="50" y="450" filter="url(#lighten)">Lighten</text> 
    </g>
  </g>  
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//text[contains(text(), 'en')]
```

This xpath gives me the following result.

```
'<text filter="url(#screen)" x="50" y="270">Screen</text>'
'<text filter="url(#darken)" x="50" y="360">Darken</text>'
'<text filter="url(#lighten)" x="50" y="450">Lighten</text>'
```